# Getting "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error

Tags: java

I get error:

```
Driver2.java:22: error: method readInitialFromFile in class VectorofContact cannot be applied to given types;
     v.readInitialFromFile("contacts");
                           ^
required: no arguments
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

The method I'm getting this error is supposed to read from a file. Before I post my code, I'm going to give some background on my code. I'm writing a small and simple address book. I have a "Contact class" that has a no-arg constructor and some getters and setters.

The comments on my Driver2 class are works in progress, you may disregard those.

This is my VectorofContact class:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class VectorofContact {

   Contact c = new Contact(); 
   private int size, capacity;
   private Contact [] addressBook; // naming the vector
   private Scanner fin;
   private PrintWriter fout;

   public VectorofContact()
   {
      addressBook = new Contact[12]; //12 cells
      size = 0; // actual number of things in the cells
      capacity = 12; //the amount of things the vector can hold
   }

   public void readInitialFromFile()
   {
       try
       {
           fin = new Scanner(new File("contacts.txt"));
       }
       catch (FileNotFoundException e)
       {
           System.out.println("Can't read from file");
       }
      while(fin.hasNext())
      {
         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
            String[] split= fin.nextLine().split(":");
            String name = split[0];
            long phoneNumber = Long.parseLong(split[1]);
            String comment = split[2];
            name = addressBook[0].getName();
            phoneNumber = addressBook[1].getphoneNumber();
            comment = addressBook[2].getComment();
         }      
      }  
   } 

   public void deleteContact(String nM)
   {
      for(int i=0; i< size; i++)
      {
         if(addressBook[i].getName().equals(nM)) //delete the name the user wants to delete
         {
              addressBook[i] = addressBook[size - 1];
              size --; //since something got deleted, size is decremented
              return;
         }  
      }
   }

   public void showByComment(String cM)
   {
      for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
      {
         if(addressBook[i].getComment().equals(cM))//reading the input from user
         {
            System.out.println(addressBook[size]);
         }
      }
   }

   public void showByName(String nM)
   {
      for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
      {
         if(addressBook[i].getName().equals(nM))
         {
            System.out.println(addressBook[size]);
         }
      }
   }

   public void save() 
   {
      try 
      {
         fout = new PrintWriter("contacts.txt");
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Can not write file?!?");
         return;
      }
         for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
         { 
            fout.print(addressBook[i] + "\t");
         }
         fout.println();

      fout.close();
   }


}
```

And this is my Driver2 class

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Driver2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      VectorofContact v = new VectorofContact();
      //orderedVectorofContact oV = new orderedVectorofContact();
      File f = new File("contacts.txt");

      if(f.exists())
      {
         v.readInitialFromFile("contacts");
      }

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String commands; 
      boolean quit; //the quit command
      boolean noContact; //if the conact doesn't exist in array.

      quit = false;
      noContact = false; 

      System.out.println("Welcome to Address Book");
      System.out.println("Would you like to use a Vector or an Ordered Vector?");
      while(!noContact)
      {
         System.out.println(v.toString());
         commands = input.next();
         switch(commands)
         {
            case "Vector" : System.out.println("Please enter your command: ");
                                                                              break;
            case "Ordered Vector" : System.out.println("Please enter your" 
                                                + " command: ");              break;
            case "add": System.out.println("Name?");
                        //oV.addContact(input.nextLine());
                        System.out.println("Phone number?");
                        //oV.addContact(input.nextLong());
                        System.out.println("Comment?quit");
                        //oV.addContact(input.nextLine());                      
                                                                              break;

            case "Find name": System.out.print("What name would you like"
                                          + " to search?");
                              v.showByName(input.nextLine());                 break;

            case "Find comment": System.out.println("Please enter the "
                                          + " comment you wish to search: ");
                                  v.showByComment(input.nextLine());          break;

            case "remove" : System.out.println("What would you like to remove?");
                            System.out.println("Removed: " );
                                        v.deleteContact(input.nextLine()); break;

            case "quit" : quit = true;
                          System.out.println("Writing contacts.txt");
                          v.save();                                           break;

            default: break;                                       
         }
         if(noContact)
         {
            System.out.println("Contact does not extist/ has not been added");
         }   
      }
   }
}
```

The "if statement" is the one spitting out the error. But it has something to do with my readInitialFromFile method in my VectorofContact class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readInitialFromFile` method has this signature:

```
public void readInitialFromFile() { /* implementation*/ }
```

This means that it accepts *no parameters*, whereas you are attempting to pass one `String` parameter here:

```
if(f.exists())
{
    v.readInitialFromFile("contacts");
}
```

Remove `"contacts"` and it'll compile. Another solution is to modify the signature of `readInitialFromFile` to accept one `String` parameter:

```
public void readInitialFromFile(String str) { /* implementation*/ }
```

Comment: I deleted contact, but now I get weird stuff in the output like :"VectorofContact@3291384d"

Comment: @oolostoo That's the default implementation of `toString()` in `Object`. You need to override the method if you want a custom representation.

Comment: @oolostoo With a search engine http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/

Comment: Now im having problems with showing by comment and name

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void readInitialFromFile()
```

This declaration says that `readInitialFromFile` takes no parameters.  But then you gave it one:

```
   v.readInitialFromFile("contacts");
```

which is confusing to the poor compiler.  Since your `readInitialFromFile` method looks like

```
public void readInitialFromFile()
{
    try
    {
        fin = new Scanner(new File("contacts.txt"));
    }
    ...
```

it looks like you're trying to set it up so that you can pass in any string as the file name, not just `"contacts"`.  So you probably want to add a `String name` parameter (or whatever parameter name you want) to the method, and then use that parameter when you use `new File` in the method body.

In general, an "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error means pretty much what it says.  The formal argument list (or parameter list) refers to the parameters you declare when you write the method; in your case, this is 0 parameters.  The actual argument (parameter) list refers to the number of parameters you give when you call on the method, which is 1 in your example.

Comment: I see what you're saying, so I have to give my method a parameter.